# How can I access html elements that were dynamically pushed into html?

Tags: html, javascript

I have got a return from a server which is a block of html, which I unfortunately cannot influence. At the moment it is being dumped into my html via AJAX.
The problem is that internet explorer doesnt recognize any elements that come through in this block of html

eg I cannot:

```
document.getElementById(someValueId)
```

because internet explorer thinks that, in the object explorer, that the div which someValueId is in is empty.

Does anyone have any idea how I can actually get to those elements?

Edit for some clarity:

I actually create a bunch of html elements on the server and push them into a div
The entire thing works in firefox, but if I try to run code like

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.form['invoice'].submit value="Confirm" />
```

The element is not found by Ie.
even a default submit input wont work.

I inspected the div I populated the data into in Ie and for some obscure reason it thinks that everything I added does not exist at all ( it is literally nowhere in my source )

I tried doing the same thing, but pushed the call into an IFrame, which meant that the code would suddenly start working ( eg I can then submit the form ), but this is causing way too many issues with other parts of the code, so I figure I want to do it properly.

Some Example code:
This is the form being returned.

```
<form action="orderNew.php?submitOrder=1" method="POST" name="invoice">      
     <input name="line[181][amount]" id="line[181][amount]" value="" size="10" onchange="isNumeric(this.id)" type="text">
     <input name="line[181][itemId]" value="181" type="hidden">          
<input type="button" onclick="document.forms['invoice'].submit()" value="Confirm" />
```

isNumeric () calls

```
function isNumeric(elemId){
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
if(document.getElementById(elemId).value.match(numericExpression)){
    return true;
}
else{
    alert('Input not numeric.');
    document.getElementById(elemId).focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

isNumeric and Confirm will never fire. 
They actually fail silently.

Comment: Can you post some of your JavaScript?

Comment: You are aware that the `input` code is invalid? (Missing a closing quote, and `document.form` doesn't exist)

Comment: @pekka sorry, typos in making the code legible, should be fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` will work fine, no matter where the HTML comes from.

You will just have to

1. actually attach the HTML to the document after the AJAX call and
2. take care you don't have multiple IDs.

Element IDs must be unique. My bet is that is your problem.

Comment: 1.Attaching the html to the document? You mean do something like div.innerhtml = $html? if not, then this might be where I am going wrong.
2. My ids are unique

Comment: @Alex nope, the innerHTML thing should be fine. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

If you call document.getElementById() **after** the AJAX call has populated the data it shouldn't have any problem finding them.  Are you sure this is not the problem?

Comment: Since the js being triggered is part of the ajax return, no

Answer (score 1):

If you wont to be be able to modify html elements that came via ajax, i would take a look at the jQuery Library, it supports Live element handling.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

This will allow you to attach event entities onto content that is not part of the document upon initial load!

Answer (score 0):

I would check whats going on by using the ie dev toolbar or try it in firefox using firebug. You should be able to examine the problem a bit more easily using these tools.

Comment: Ie believes that my div is empty for some odd reason.
It works well in FF though

Comment: How are you confirming that IE thinks your div is empty? doing a view source will never show you changes made after the page load, you'll have to use somethign like I imagine the IE dev toolbar to analyze the "live" state of the page. May be you know that but thought I'd make sure. :)

Comment: Is it well formed etc? You could probly print the div to an alert in IE to see whats in it if you can't the ie dev toolbar.

Comment: just looked at the question - square brackets on ids are invalid:http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name - not sure this will actually make difference but might be good to eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot... Did not close the form tag. Thanks for everyone that helped.

Comment: After seeing your code, you do not need to use getElementById in that case.  In your onChange just use: onchange="isNumeric(this)" and it will pass the element without having to "get" it again later using the id.